# Selenium chromedriver in relative path for mac and python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get selenium to use chromedriver on mac.

I have downloaded the mac version of chromedriver and added it to the same folder as my python file. I am then using:

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

however it doesn't seem to be opening.

This works fine in windows but just not working on mac. anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have to provide a path to binary when creating an instance of `webdrive.Chrome()`:

```
chromedriver = "/path/to/chromedriver/folder"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

or `chromedriver` has to be in you `PATH`. You can add `chromedriver` to `PATH` with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/chromedriver/folder
```

Answer (score 8):

You might need to install it with :
`brew install chromedriver --cask` or
`brew install chromedriver`

and then do
`which chromedriver`

You will get the relevant path.